# Unable to enable network debugging, unable to debug Api.Why?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

When using react-native-debugger to debug the API, it is impossible to follow the official documentation. Unable to debug. API, can anyone know why? Detailed screenshots are here. Thank you.

https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger/issues/784

[image]

“Enable Network Inspect” Click without response after debugging is turned on, there is no response, and the request record is still not visible, and the request sent by the app cannot be seen.